# How to load spark graphx from objectFile

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

In spark-shell i run my code like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.graphx.{Edge, Graph, GraphLoader, VertexId}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

val users: RDD[(VertexId, Map[String, String])] =
      sc.parallelize(Array(
        (1L, Map("a" -> "a")),
        (2L, Map("b" -> "b")),
        (3L, Map("c" -> "c")),
        (4L, Map("d" -> "d"))
      ))

    val edgs: RDD[Edge[String]] =
      sc.parallelize(Array(
        Edge(1L, 2L, "1_2"),
        Edge(2L, 3L, "2_3"),
        Edge(3L, 1L, "3_1"),
        Edge(4L, 1L, "4_1"),
        Edge(4L, 3L, "4_3")
      ))


    val graph = Graph.apply(users, edgs)

    graph.edges.saveAsObjectFile("/Users/test/edges")
    graph.vertices.saveAsObjectFile("/Users/test/vertices")

    val vertices = sc.objectFile[(VertexId, Map[String, String])]("/Users/test/edges")
    val edges = sc.objectFile[Edge[String]]("/Users/test/vertices")

    val un = Graph.apply(vertices, edges)

    un.edges.foreach(println)
```

the error like this,my spark version is 2.1.1.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:107)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:107)
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:844)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:844)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1005)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:996)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:936)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:996)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:700)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD.compute(EdgeRDD.scala:50)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

so the error looks like cant cast obejectfile to graphs.
My question is  how to store a graphx as object file and reload it ,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I make a stupid error:
val vertices = sc.objectFile(VertexId, Map[String, String])
val edges = sc.objectFileEdge[String]

load the edges from the wrong file.

so,this is no problem use by this way